# Invalid Operations on Trig Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Reviewing Trig I come across this problem :
$\text{Solve for all real $x$ such that } 2\sqrt{2} \cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\cos(x) + 2.$

The first thing I did was use the cosine half-angle identity get this look...

$$2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{\cos(x)+1}{2}}=\cos(x)+2$$

I then squared both sides of the equation (I believe this is an error but can't pinpoint why).

The rest looks like this :

$$8\frac{\cos(x)+1}{2}=\cos^2(x)+4\cos(x)+4$$

$$4\cos(x)+4=\cos^2(x)+4\cos(x)+4$$

$$0=\cos^2(x)$$

Then $x = \left\{\pm \frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n \ \middle|\ n \in\mathbb Z \right\}$

Now, I believe this set does contain all $x$ which satisfy the orignial equation, but it definitely contains invalid solutions as well.

What specifically did I do wrong here and, if possible, are there any hard and fast rules about when algebraic operations on trig equations will change the solution set?

Comment: Any time you square both sides you can introduce extraneous solutions.

Comment: Hint: solve $2\sqrt{2} \cos\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)=\cos\left(2\,\dfrac x2\right) + 2=2\cos^2\left(\,\dfrac x2\right) + 1$ instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to solve an equation of the type $f(x)=g(x)$, it is perfectly fine to do $f^2(x)=g^2(x)$. The solutions of the first equation will also be solutions of the second one. But there is a real possibility of creating new ones. An extreme case of this is the equation $x=-x$, whose only solution is $x=0$. But *every* real number is a solution of the equation $x^2=(-x)^2$.

In your specific case, take all solutions  that you got and check which ones are solutions of the original equation.

Answer (score 2):

$$2\sqrt{2} \cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\cos(x) + 2.$$

By the double-angle formula for the cosine, which says $\cos(2\theta)= 2\cos^2\theta-1,$ applied in the case where $\theta = x/2,$ we get:

$$ 2\sqrt{2} \cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)= \left[ 2\cos^2\left(\frac x 2\right) - 1\right] + 2. $$

$$
2\sqrt 2 \, u = 2u^2 + 1.
$$

This is a quadratic equation. Solve it for $u$ and then write $\cos\dfrac x 2 = \text{the solution for $u$}$ and solve that for $x.$